# How to get specific headers (spring-boot application) and pass to controller?

Tags: spring-boot

[image]

I have a controller in spring boot. I want to get the formId from Form Data (see the image above). @RequestHeader(value="formId") doesn't work. How to get the value?

Answer (score 1):

formId is not from the header but the from form data which is the request body.

You can get it like in this example:

```
@GetMapping("foo)
public String foo(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData) {

     String formId = formData.get("formId");
     // your code
}
```

Comment: The form data appears when user uploads a file which calls ../api/v1/upload, now I want to get the form data. So i call controller (upload function) from another controller to which the Request body is passed. I tried, but it doesn't work. like " return "redirect:/foo";

Comment: You should show some code otherwise it's hard to help you

Answer (score 0):

First you need below dependency,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Then you can get Form data value using below example code,

```
@PostMapping("/foo")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> getData(@FormParam("formId") String formId) {
    System.out.println(formId);
}
```

In here formParam variable name and parameter name should be equal.

Comment: No the formId is not in the header! And @RequestHeader would be right way if it would be in the header.